# How to insert data into table in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

i have a table **`TransactionUpdate`** with columns `TransactionUpdateId`, `OrderNumber`,`BalanceAmount`,`TotalOrderAmount`,`LinkToCustomerMasterId`,`LinkToLocationId`,`LastUpdateDate`

i want to insert data into **`TransactionUpdate`**

i have tried this. but only once data is being inserted. after that data is not inserted in table

```
TransactionUpdate objTransaction = new TransactionUpdate();
     objTransaction.OrderNumber = objBooking.OrderNumber;
                            objTransaction.BalanceAmount = 0;
                            objTransaction.OrderTotalAmt = objBooking.TotalOrderAmt;
                            objTransaction.LinkToCustomerMasterId = objBooking.LinkCustomerMasterId;
                            objTransaction.LinkToLocationId = objBooking.LinktoLocationMasterId;
                            objTransaction.OrderType = "Send booking";
                            objTransaction.LastUpdaeDate = DateTime.Now;

                            int AddCOD = clsFranchies.AddCODCustomerOrderTransaction(objTransaction);
```

**method:AddCODCustomerOrderTransaction**

```
public static int AddCODCustomerOrderTransaction(TransactionUpdate transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WMSDataContext dc = new WMSDataContext())
                {
                    TransactionUpdate objtransactionAddCOD = new TransactionUpdate();
                    objtransactionAddCOD = transaction;
                    dc.TransactionUpdates.InsertOnSubmit(objtransactionAddCOD);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                clsError.WriteError(ex);
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

I am using **Linq to sql**, ***clsFranchise*** is class file.

Comment: you mention "once data", it means: first data or first time?

Comment: first time. see. if my table is blank. and i add one entry. then insert is working. but if i try to insert another time, table is not changing. if i again delete that first data(row) and insert it will insert. and then i insert, no insert will perform @NhânNguyễn

Comment: so in short only first time it is inserted. not second time. if i clear the table then i insert, that means it will be first data. so it will be inserted. but after that no insert will perform@NhânNguyễn

Comment: In second time, data is the same in first time?

Comment: i have set `TransactionUpdateId` as a primary key. Not auto increment. does it matter??

Comment: You tried to increase manual TransactionUpdateId.

Comment: yaa. i have made change. Is Identity marked yes. Now its working. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set TransactionUpdateId when you are inserting a record.

So by default (if it is a integer) then it is taking TransactionUpdateId = 0.
So here when you are adding 1st entry into table, record gets added with primary key 0. 
But when your are trying 2 time, primary key isn't allowing you to enter 2nd record with duplicate primary key value 0.

```
You can resolve this issue by 2 ways:
1) Set primary key to auto increment.
2) While inserting record set primary key value to new value. Like newValue = Max(TransactionUpdateId ) + 1;
```

For 2nd way: modify below function:

```
public static int AddCODCustomerOrderTransaction(TransactionUpdate transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WMSDataContext dc = new WMSDataContext())
                {
                    TransactionUpdate objtransactionAddCOD = new TransactionUpdate();
                    objtransactionAddCOD = transaction;

            var newTransactionUpdateID = dc.TransactionUpdates.Max(s = >s.TransactionUpdateId);

            objtransactionAddCOD.TransactionUpdateId = newTransactionUpdateID == null ? 1: (newTransactionUpdateID + 1);
                    dc.TransactionUpdates.InsertOnSubmit(objtransactionAddCOD);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                clsError.WriteError(ex);
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Please let me know is this works for you ?